# How can I run time.sleep() passing in minutes instead of seconds?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a timer program and am wondering how I can make

```
      time.sleep(#)
```

cause the program to sleep for # minutes instead # seconds?

Comment: `time.sleep(minutes * 60)`?

Comment: No, i made it as an input for the users so i want it to when they type "1" it registers as 1 minute instead of 1 second.

Comment: @H.Alaa The user inputs `1` minute and the program transforms it to `60` seconds for them. You can't change the nature of a function like `time.sleep` unless you modify the source code of Python, which would likely break many applications.

Answer (score 9):

multiply your minutes by 60 or create a function which will do this automaticly:

```
from time import sleep
def sleep_minutes(minutes):
    sleep(minutes * 60)
```